# simplification of F=A'B'C'+A'B'C+ABC'

Tags: boolean-algebra

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpRAQ.jpg)

have i grouped them right?
is the answer A'B'+C' or not???

Comment: can someone explain me how to circle on the karnaugh map?

Comment: The top-left circle containing two 1's is correct, but notice the circle across the corner contains no don't care. Otherwise you're correct.

Comment: that means that i cant cirlcle the corners??

Comment: You can, but you read off the circle incorrectly.

Comment: can you be more specific? shouldnt have i circled the top left with the  bot right???

Comment: Please edit your previous question by clicking the "edit" button to add more context instead of asking the exact same question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't group together two diagonal cells; the cells you group must always be adjacent to each other ... touching in a corner is not enough.

Indeed, here is a counterexample to your proposed equivalence:

$A = 0, B=1, C=0$

Then $A'B'C'+A'B'C+ABC'=0+0+0=0$

but $A'B'+C'=0+1=1$

And another counterexample is:

$A = 1, B=0, C=0$

For then $A'B'C'+A'B'C+ABC'=0+0+0=0$

but $A'B'+C'=0+1=1$

How did I find those counterexamples? Because these are the top right and bottom left corners that you mistakenly grouped into $C'$ when putting together the top left and bottom right corner.